# UINavigationBar background image with iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a background image to the NavigationBar of an UINavigationBarController

```
[viewController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In my assets I have a

- NavBarBackground.png,
- NavBarBackground@x2.png,
- NavBarBackground@x3.png

Apple documentation says about resolutions :

- iPhone 5/5c/5s/6 @x2 (retina)
- iPhone 6+ @x3 (retina HD)

BUT

- iPhone 5(&co) have a screen width of 640px
- iPhone 6 have a screen width of 750px

How can I handle iPhone 6 case without having another image that I'll need to named with extension in my setBackgroundImage method only for iPhone 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Navigation Bar on iPhone 6/iPhone 6+ has a different Aspect Ratio comparing to all other iPhone models. 
So in this case, you need a different Image Set.

But, if the image is just a color background, I suggest using the following code:

```
[viewController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefaults
```

And implement the following method:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: It's a gradient in my case. Apple should have added this case in an image set like '@x'1 '@x2R4' '@2xR4.7' for cases like iPhone 6. Thanks anyway :)